# java.util.logging.Filter does not work when set in config-Class

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I am trying to set a up a `java.util.logging.Filter` to discard some logs that pollute my standard.out.

I'am starting my jvm with `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/my/logging.properties` and in the properties file `config = my.package.OWBDelegateHanderLogDiscarder` is set.

When I debug I can see that the logger is retrieved and the filter set. But my `isLoggable` method will never be called.

Any ideas?

```
package my.package;
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class OWBDelegateHanderLogDiscarder {

/*
 * See org.apache.webbeans.config.OWBLogConst.ERROR_0012
 */
private static final String OWB_LOG_CONST_ERROR_0012 = "ERROR_0012";

private static final String LOGGER_NAME = "org.apache.webbeans.decorator.DelegateHandler";

public OWBDelegateHanderLogDiscarder() {
    Logger delegateHandlerLogger = Logger.getLogger(DelegateHandler.class.getName());
    if (delegateHandlerLogger != null) {
        delegateHandlerLogger.setFilter(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
                if (!LOGGER_NAME.equals(record.getLoggerName())) {
                    return true;
                }
                String message = record.getMessage();
                return !(message != null && message.startsWith(OWB_LOG_CONST_ERROR_0012));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update**

I'm using CDI in my application and I found out that everything works fine until I call `WebBeansContext currentInstance = WebBeansContext.currentInstance();`. Seems to be a bug and I have to file it at OpenWebBeans.

Can I somehow close my question or should i just delete it?

Comment: You should answer your own question and include the information and or resolution from the bug report you file.